# Different image output when saving as

Tags: php, html, image

I want to be able to generate a different image (with watermark) when the user save the image.

I know that :

- Broswer send text/html when it's direct image access and image/jpeg (image content-type) when it's included in a src=""

So if the browser query the server from a src="", it send the good content-type. If the broswer go on the image url it does send text/html,application/html+xml, etc...

Anyone know how to make the watermark happen if the user do the command "Save as" ?

Thanks

Comment: `Anyone know how to make the watermark happen if the user do the command "Save as"` You can't.

Comment: Go on http://9gag.com/ and try to save an image, see the watermark is added. Can you explain ?

Comment: @DavidBélanger They just crop that with a negative margin. The ‘watermark’ is already on the image.

Comment: @Gumbo Thanks! So stupid I didn't even think about that... thanks a lot !

Comment: Weird design, but yes, @Gumbo is correct.

Comment: Yes it is weird... I tought I could use GD to generate watermark on the fly using the sent header by the browser... I did manage to know when it was direct access or included into a src="" but saving as was another pair of hand... and the negative margin come to solve everything and will of corse use less horse power.

Comment: I haven't checked, but if it's true that browsers send a different accept header it is possible to do something about it (allthough I suspect that different browsers behave differently). In that case you use an intermediate script (such as PHP) and call that one instead of the image file name. Ex: `image.php?name=lolcat.jpg`. The PHP script would be responsible for generating the correct image depending on the Accept-Header. But @Gumbo's example of a cropped image is a more elegant solution in my opinion

Comment: @Optimist I totaly agree. I did create a script already who give different results depending on the header. I'll put the script in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most elegant solution gave above was to create a box over the image who's less higher (and will hide the watermark) who's has been generated before (when uploading the picture let's say).

This way the CSS hide the white box below the picture and when someone use "Save as" the box is there. No ressource is used on the server.

Here's the solution based on the browser header I developped. Do not work with "Save as" but work for direct access picture and src=""

```
    <?php
    #...

    # Require PHP to work as a module in apache
    $SentHeaders = apache_request_headers();
    #$Watermark = strpos($SentHeaders['Accept'], 'text');
    $Watermark = preg_match_all('/text/', $SentHeaders['Accept'], $matches);

    # Set the header
    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 

    # HHeader required
    ($Image->ContentType) ? header('Content-Type: '.$Image->ContentType) : header('Location: /404');

    # Accès direct / save as
    if($Watermark){
        # Direct Image Access
        #...
    } else {
        # Image included in src=""
        #...
    }
    #...
    ?>
```